# Repository query conditions, dependencies and DRY

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, dry, ddd-repositories

To keep it simple, let's suppose an application which has `Accounts` and `Users`. Each account may have any number of users. There's also 3 consumers of `UserRepository`:

- An admin interface which may list all users
- Public front-end which may list all users
- An account authenticated API which should only list it's own users

Assuming `UserRepository` is something like this:

```php
class UsersRepository extends DatabaseAbstraction {
    private function query() {
        return $this->database()->select('users.*');
    }
    public function getAll() {
        return $this->query()->exec();
    }
    // IMPORTANT:
    // Tons of other methods for searching, filtering,
    // joining of other tables, ordering and such...
}
```

Keeping in mind the comment above, and the necessity to abstract user querying conditions, How should I handle querying of users filtering by `account_id`? I can picture three possible roads:

#### 1. Should I create an `AccountUsersRepository`?

```php
class AccountUsersRepository extends UserRepository {
    public function __construct(Account $account) {
        $this->account = $account;
    }
    private function query() {
        return parent::query()
            ->where('account_id', '=', $this->account->id);
    }
}
```

*This has the advantage of reducing the duplication of `UsersRepository` methods, but doesn't quite fit into anything I've read about DDD so far (I'm rookie by the way)*

#### 2. Should I put it as a method on `AccountsRepository`?

```php
class AccountsRepository extends DatabaseAbstraction {
    public function getAccountUsers(Account $account) {
        return $this->database()
            ->select('users.*')
            ->where('account_id', '=', $account->id)
            ->exec();
    }
}
```

*This requires the duplication of all `UserRepository` methods and may need another `UserQuery` layer, that implements those querying logic on chainable way.*

#### 3. Should I query `UserRepository` from within my account entity?

```php
class Account extends Entity {
    public function getUsers() {
        return UserRepository::findByAccountId($this->id);
    }
}
```

*This feels more like an aggregate root for me, but introduces dependency of `UserRepository` on `Account` entity, which may violate a few principles.*

#### 4. Or am I missing the point completely?

Maybe there's an even better solution?

**Footnotes:** Besides permissions being a Service concern, in my understanding, they shouldn't implement SQL query but leave that to repositories since those may not even be SQL driven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching all users belonging to an account is more of an UI concern. My suggestion is use your MVC controller(like AccountAdminController?) invoke the UserRepository.findByAccountId() directly.

I think Aggregates should be returned only by its own repository.

Comment: Just to add: by creating custom repository methods you extract the domain features which helps to make the business (domain) logic clearer in the code base. 

Eg. UserRepository.findByAccountId() is better than UserRepository.findBy($query) because it shows the relationships between User and Agent. There is no need to create custom query object every time you need to show all the Users belonging to some Account.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about, it makes perfect sense to treat that as an UI concern. Although, it raises another question: since we have complex dynamic queries besides that `account_id`, based on user input, should I treat my repository as some kind of decorator around a `IQuery` object?

Comment: @vFragosop I'd like to use a criteria object when building  dynamic queries, something like UserRepository.findBy(UserCriteria criteria). Does IQuery object have an special meaning in php?

Comment: Not actually, by `IQuery` I meant an interface for building SQL queries. I did read somethings about criteria yesterday, but I can't really figure out how a repository can translate a criteria to something like `LEFT JOIN b WHERE b.foo = bar` without creating even more classes or dependencies. (PHP lacks a lot on DDD examples and pattern implementations)

Comment: @vFragosop In a simplest case(without orm framework), you could build your sql based on the criteria, something like " if criteria.getEqFoo is not null then sql =  sql + 'LEFT JOIN b WHERE b.foo = ' + criteria.getEqFoo()"